# What is common between environments within a shell terminal session?

Tags: bash, session, shell, ssh, gnu-screen

I have a custom shell script that runs each time a user logs in or identity is assumed, its been placed in /etc/profile.d and performs some basic env variable operations.  Recently I added some code so that if screen is running it will reattach it without needing me to type anything.  There are some problems however.  If I log-in as root, and su - to another user, the code runs a second time.  Is there a variable I can set when the code runs the first time that will prevent a second run of the code?

I thought to write something to the disk but then I dont want to prevent the code from running if I begin a new terminal session.  Here is the code in question.  It first attempts to reattach - if unsuccessful because its already attached (as it might be on an interruped session) it will 'take' the session back.

```
screen -r

if [ -z "$STY" ]; then
    exec screen -dR
fi
```

Ultimately this bug prevents me from substituting user to another user because as soon as I do so, it grabs the screen session and puts me right back where I started.  Pretty frustrating

Comment: I understand where you're going with the suggestion however - like I responded - I did add this code to the profile directory yet when I substitute user (which should only be running the 'bashrc' according to the article) the code is still run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ${PPID} of the shell you get when you su will be the su command.  So the output of

```
ps -o command= $PPID
```

will begin with the letters `su`, so test for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get this right if you read the following post (and the man for your favorite shell)
[Question about login vs profile](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/etcprofile-v.s.-etcbashrc-273992/)

Comment: Well if I understand this article correctly then I am doing exactly what I should be doing (yet the bug persists).  I added the system wide script to the /etc/profile.d - and it shouldnt run when I substitute user which should be on the level of a 'bashrc' action, if I am not mistaken .. maybe I am